# How to create an exe for .NetCore service

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, topshelf

I have created a service application in C# using Topshelf.  I created it however for the .NetCore platform and not .Net framework.  Now I want to deploy the service app on another machine to test it off the development area.  It seems that after the build in Visual studio I only find a DLL and a .exe.  Is there something speficic I need to do to get the exe or is it because of the .NetCore Platform that I only have a dll and how do I go to deploying the service?  What I should add here is that as I created the project in Visual Studio,  I created a Consol App (.NET Core) and the TopShelf framework was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dll to run .net core. To run .NET Core you just need to have installed .NET Core Runtime which can be found [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download). Then on this machine you just use **dotnet ApplicationName.dll** in cmd / powershell. 
If you want to create exe file instead of dll then you should use command: **dotnet publish -r win10-x64**

More information you can find in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/).